# Accessing Docker ( installed with Kitematic/MacOSX) via Remote API

Tags: docker, remoteapi

How can I access my Docker artifacts installed via Kitematic on MacOSX using Remote API (*http*)

Currently I see that it is availble via *tcp*...

My **docker env.** details

```
DOCKER_HOST=tcp://182.159.98.120:2375 
DOCKER_CERT_PATH=/Users/IamUser/.docker/machine/machines/dev
DOCKER_TLS_VERIFY=1
```

Navigating to `http://182.159.98.120:2375/version` does not work.